# Global variable in python, initliazing and terminating

Tags: python, function, raspberry-pi, global-variables

I'm making a program that lets me record video using the rapsberry pi camera lib for python, there's one small issue, when you run `camera = picamera.PiCamera()` the camera is enabled and being used until the end of the program, what I would like to do is only enable it when recording and stop when recording is done but still keep my program active.

What I need:
How do I create a global variable for the `picamera` and how do I terminate it.

Part of my code that's relevant:

```
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
filename = ""

#Start recording video into raw file
def start_record():
                print("Starting recording");
                reset_tmp()
                global filename
                filename = "vid/" + str(int(time.time()));
                camera.start_recording(filename+".h264");

#Stop recording and convert h264 raw file to mp4 and remove raw file
def stop_record():
                print("Stopping recording");
                reset_tmp()
                global filename
                camera.stop_recording()
                os.system("MP4Box -fps 30 -add "+filename+".h264"+" "+filename+".mp4");
                os.system("rm "+filename+".h264");
```

Updated version of code, functional
for those looking for the solution of the title you must use the `del` keyword to get rid of variables but the `picamera` library has a function called `.close()` to terminate the object, here's my fixed code:

```
camera = None
filename = ""

#Start recording video into raw file
def start_record():
                print("Starting recording");
                reset_tmp()
                global filename
                filename = "vid/" + str(int(time.time()));

                global camera
                camera = picamera.PiCamera()
                camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
                camera.start_recording(filename+".h264");

#Stop recording and convert h264 raw file to mp4 and remove raw file
def stop_record():
                print("Stopping recording");
                reset_tmp()
                global filename
                global camera
                camera.stop_recording()
                camera.close()
                os.system("MP4Box -fps 30 -add "+filename+".h264"+" "+filename+".mp4");
                os.system("rm "+filename+".h264");
```

Comment: put the line that starts the recording inside the function start_record.

Comment: That doesn't work because I need to access that same variable inside the other function

Comment: I'd recommend taking some time to look up how functions work, and how to pass parameters between them.

Comment: @Chris is right. start the recording in start_record, have that function return the variable you need, then pass that variable to stop_record.

Comment: Already got something that works so far, only issue is shutting off the camera when recording is done.

Answer (score 2):

No need for globals here. Just use return values:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

import picamera

def start_record(resolution=(1920, 1080)):
    """Start recording video into raw file"""
    print("Starting recording")
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = resolution
    reset_tmp()
    filename = os.path.join('vid', '{}.h264'.format(int(time.time())))
    camera.start_recording(filename)
    return camera, filename


def stop_record(camera, filename):
    """Stop recording and convert h264 raw file to mp4 and remove raw file"""
    print("Stopping recording")
    reset_tmp()
    camera.stop_recording()
    mp4_fn = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.mp4'
    subprocess.call(['MP4Box', '-fps', '30', '-add', mp4_fn])
    os.remove(filename)
```

Now call the start function:

```
camera, filename = start_record()
```

and later the stop function:

```
stop_record(camera, filename)
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
camera = None
camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
filename = ""

#Start recording video into raw file
def start_record():
                print("Starting recording");
                reset_tmp()
                global filename
                filename = "vid/" + str(int(time.time()));

                global camera
                camera = picamera.PiCamera()
                camera.start_recording(filename+".h264");
```

The basic idea would be to move the code to start the camera into a funktion - where global can be used to modify a global variable.

Comment: This works but I still need to terminate the variable in the 2nd function, how do I do that?

Comment: YOu are already doing that, see     camera.stop_recording(). If that is not sufficient, yaou will have to consult the docs

Comment: Yeah I figured that out a minute ago, I just edited the post, thanks for the help guys :)